# C# , Execute external exe (not embedded exe) without specifying entire DIR aka Drive Letter to File

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I can easily execute an exe installed in a default location ( like notepad or cmd) or even a third party Program. However, I have to specify from drive letter to exe and I just wanna write it so it looks in it Resources or whatever folder to find it so that it works on other machines as well. Kinda like portableapps.com or symenu. I'm just trying to make my life easier. not copy-write or make money. I want to have a folder with this program with the exe's inside of it. want this so that I can update the exe's as needed. the program won't work once moved to another machine. if I have to specify c://blah/blah/blah.exe. In order to be portable. I'd need to be able to do something like **MyResource/blah.exe or **MiFolder/Blah.exe. on another note... it seems in Visual studio 2017 that you cannot embed much else other than Images and text.

Comment: What are you asking? Are you asking how to use relative paths? Also, you store anything you like in a resource file.

Comment: [Running programs by typing some alias in Windows](https://superuser.com/q/193000/573723)

Comment: The Environment.CurrentDirectory must be set correctly.  It is the worst global variable you can think of, you don't control its initial value and you can't see when it changes.  Don't do it.

Comment: John- Yes! Sounds like what I'm looking to do. You worded it simply. Going to research more using that term. Man the simplest of things.

Comment: How do I add Resources such as an exe in Visual Studio 2017. everything I find is old documentation that isn't applicable in the new version as far as I can tell. I am very new/Noob and try to research, but need some help asking the right questions.